# GAN training the average of my train data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, gan, dropout

I have been training a GAN with 1D convolutional layers on sinus functions. However if I start varying my sinus (random amplitude for example), the model generates only the average of the random range. So if I give the amplitude a uniform range of (0,1], after training my generator only produces sinus functions with amplitude 0.5.

When training on batch, I sample n=batch_size samples from function;

```
x = np.array(np.tile(np.linspace(-3 * np.pi, 3 * np.pi, num=ts_dim), n).reshape(n, ts_dim))
y = np.random.rand(n,1)*np.sin(x)
```

[image: Train data sample]

I tried using MC dropout (dropout not only in training, also in prediction) to get generated timeseries from a probabilistic distribution. This way I steer the generator into outputing also 'less plausible' timeseries. It seemed to help a little, but still the generated functions are around amplitude 0.5.

Are there any other ways to overcome this behaviour?

Comment: Could you provide an example of data you are using?

Comment: Included sample of the data now

Comment: What loss function do you apply?

Comment: Binary-cross entropy for both generator (Adam optimizer) and discriminator (SGD)

Comment: Found out the problem, this is called mode collapse. The discriminator is trained for a single data instance because the optimization of this instance is most beneficial. However it then ignores the other possible instances, not much you can do about it other then using a different kind of GAN network (W-GAN)